# TO_CHAR returning incorrect results when comparing to date string in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Im trying to write a query which gets the first business day of the month of the current year. The rules are if the 1st of the month is a Saturday/Sunday then take the following Monday's date. Additionally if it is 1st January in any case always take the next working date (Friday, Saturday, Sunday take the following Monday, and all other cases take the next working day).

The logic works fine from February to December but for January it is returning 2 rows for the date calculation. One which is correct and one which is incorrect.

The problem I think is coming from, when Im trying to compare the the sysdate with '01.01'.

Please find my workings below. All data is calculated using dual so this can be run without creating additional tables.

You will see 2 rows are returned for January (first is incorrect and second is correct):

```
BD_DATE   DAY_NUM   ADD_DAYS DATE_CALC
--------- ------- ---------- ---------
01-JAN-20 4                0 01-JAN-20
01-JAN-20 4                1 02-JAN-20
01-FEB-20 7                2 03-FEB-20
01-MäR-20 1                1 02-MäR-20
01-APR-20 4                0 01-APR-20
01-MAI-20 6                0 01-MAI-20
01-JUN-20 2                0 01-JUN-20
01-JUL-20 4                0 01-JUL-20
01-AUG-20 7                2 03-AUG-20
01-SEP-20 3                0 01-SEP-20
01-OKT-20 5                0 01-OKT-20
01-NOV-20 1                1 02-NOV-20
01-DEZ-20 3                0 01-DEZ-20

13 rows selected.
```

My SQL query is:

```
/* Formatted on 01.04.2020 18:37:56 (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */
WITH dateparam
     AS (    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 AS mydate
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY TRUNC (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1, 'YYYY') =
                       TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))
  SELECT DISTINCT
         ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1) bd_date,
         TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') day_num,
         /*TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01') THEN
                                                   (DECODE (
                                                       (to_char(add_months(last_day(mydate)+1,-1), 'fmD')),
                                                       6, 3,
                                                       7, 2,
                                                       1, 1,
                                                       1))
                                                ELSE*/
         CASE
            WHEN TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01') 
            THEN
               CASE
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          7
                  THEN
                     2
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          6
                  THEN
                     3
                  ELSE
                     1
               END
            ELSE
               CASE
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          7
                  THEN
                     2
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          1
                  THEN
                     1
                  ELSE
                     0
               END
         END
            add_days,
         ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1)
         + CASE
              WHEN TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01')
              THEN
                 (DECODE (
                     (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD')),
                     6, 3,
                     7, 2,
                     1, 1,
                     1))
              ELSE
                 (DECODE (
                     (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD')),
                     7, 2,
                     1, 1,
                     0))
           END
            date_calc
    FROM dateparam
ORDER BY 1;
```

I have tried using both `DECODE`and `CASE`and both blocks return the same results.

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Comment: What about other holidays apart from 1st of January?

Comment: Note, result of `TO_CHAR(..., 'D')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` setting, it may change at any time.

Comment: Currently this part of code is only to be used for monthly tasks so I only need to worry about 1st Jan. NLS settings isn't the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. Its nothing to do with NLS but rather with the column name im passing to the to_char. Instead of `mydate`I should've been substituting it with `bd_date`.

To show my working:

```
WITH dateparam
     AS (    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 AS mydate
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY TRUNC (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1, 'YYYY') =
                       TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))
  SELECT
         mydate,
         ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1) bd_date,
         TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') day_num,
         CASE
            WHEN TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01') 
            THEN
               CASE
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          7
                  THEN
                     2
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          6
                  THEN
                     3
                  ELSE
                     1
               END               
            ELSE
               CASE
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          7
                  THEN
                     2
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          1
                  THEN
                     1
                  ELSE
                     0
               END
         END
            add_days
         /*ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1)
         + CASE
              WHEN TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01')
              THEN
                 (DECODE (
                     (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD')),
                     6, 3,
                     7, 2,
                     1, 1,
                     1))
              ELSE
                 (DECODE (
                     (TO_CHAR (ADD_MON(LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD')),
                     7, 2,
                     1, 1,
                     0))
           END
            date_calc*/
    FROM dateparam where mydate <= '03JAN2020'
ORDER BY 1;
```

Yields:

```
MYDATE    BD_DATE   DAY_NUM   ADD_DAYS
--------- --------- ------- ----------
01-JAN-20 01-JAN-20 4                1
02-JAN-20 01-JAN-20 4                0
03-JAN-20 01-JAN-20 4                0

3 rows selected.
```

The problem was in my original code:

```
WHEN TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01')
```

This does the calculation for 01.01 and 02.01 but the bd_date is the same for all the days in January. So once I do a `distinct`on all the rows in January I will end up with the two rows as shown above, once I remove the column mydate.

The corrected comparison should be on bd_date instead:

```
WHEN TO_CHAR ( ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01') --Get bd_date using mydate
```

Working code:

```
/* Formatted on 02.04.2020 10:42:53 (QP5 v5.163.1008.3004) */
WITH dateparam
     AS (    SELECT TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1 AS mydate
               FROM DUAL
         CONNECT BY TRUNC (TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1, 'YYYY') =
                       TRUNC (SYSDATE, 'YYYY'))
  SELECT DISTINCT
         ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1) bd_date,
         TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') day_num,
         CASE
            WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'DD.MM') IN
                    ('01.01')
            THEN
               CASE
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          7
                  THEN
                     2
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          6
                  THEN
                     3
                  ELSE
                     1
               END
            ELSE
               CASE
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          7
                  THEN
                     2
                  WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD') =
                          1
                  THEN
                     1
                  ELSE
                     0
               END
         END
            add_days,
         ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1)
         + CASE
              WHEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'DD.MM') IN
                      ('01.01')
              THEN
                 (DECODE (
                     (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD')),
                     6, 3,
                     7, 2,
                     1, 1,
                     1))
              ELSE
                 (DECODE (
                     (TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'fmD')),
                     7, 2,
                     1, 1,
                     0))
           END
            date_calc
    FROM dateparam
ORDER BY 1;
```

Results:

```
BD_DATE   DAY_NUM   ADD_DAYS DATE_CALC
--------- ------- ---------- ---------
01-JAN-20 4                1 02-JAN-20
01-FEB-20 7                2 03-FEB-20
01-MäR-20 1                1 02-MäR-20
01-APR-20 4                0 01-APR-20
01-MAI-20 6                0 01-MAI-20
01-JUN-20 2                0 01-JUN-20
01-JUL-20 4                0 01-JUL-20
01-AUG-20 7                2 03-AUG-20
01-SEP-20 3                0 01-SEP-20
01-OKT-20 5                0 01-OKT-20
01-NOV-20 1                1 02-NOV-20
01-DEZ-20 3                0 01-DEZ-20

12 rows selected.
```

I agree with all the other suggestions in this post that the original set of dates could and should have been reduced before doing my calculations, instead of fetching all calendar dates of the year. I just needed to understand what I could have done to fix my original code.

Thank you everyone for your contributions!

Comment: `WHEN TO_CHAR ( ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1), 'DD.MM') IN ('01.01')` will never not be true so you can get rid of that outer `CASE` statement and the entirety of its `ELSE` clause and, as I said in my answer, you can rewrite `ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1)` to a much simpler statement of `TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' )`. Doing that gets you to the final query in my answer.

Comment: Im not sure why I need to get rid of it? I still need to have a special case to handle 1st January, where I always need to move the date to the next working day.

Answer (score 2):

`TO_CHAR` relies on the NLS settings including territory and language. If you want to do the calculation independently of the NLS settings then you can use the fact that an ISO week always starts on a Monday and calculate the number of days difference between the first day of the month and the start (Monday) of the ISO week containing that first day of the month:

```sql
WITH months ( first_day ) AS (
  SELECT CASE LEVEL
         WHEN 1 THEN TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ) + INTERVAL '1' DAY
         ELSE ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), LEVEL - 1 )
         END
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
SELECT first_day
       + CASE first_day - TRUNC( first_day, 'IW' )
         WHEN 5 THEN 2 -- Saturday
         WHEN 6 THEN 1 -- Sunday
                ELSE 0 -- Weekday
         END
         AS first_business_day
FROM   months;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | FIRST_BUSINESS_DAY |
> | :----------------- |
> | 2020-01-02 (THU)   |
> | 2020-02-03 (MON)   |
> | 2020-03-02 (MON)   |
> | 2020-04-01 (WED)   |
> | 2020-05-01 (FRI)   |
> | 2020-06-01 (MON)   |
> | 2020-07-01 (WED)   |
> | 2020-08-03 (MON)   |
> | 2020-09-01 (TUE)   |
> | 2020-10-01 (THU)   |
> | 2020-11-02 (MON)   |
> | 2020-12-01 (TUE)   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c37499f1a9c41946a3ead68d541867e5)*

---

> Any ideas what I have done wrong?

The query is too complicated. You are generating all the days of the year in the sub-query factoring (`WITH`) clause when you are interested in only the first days of the month and this means that in the second part of the query you are replacing each day with the first of the month using:

```sql
ADD_MONTHS (LAST_DAY (mydate) + 1, -1)
```

Which could be simplified to just:

```sql
TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' )
```

Or, if you just generated in incrementing months to start with then you wouldn't even need truncate as you would only have rows for the first day of the month:

```sql
WITH months ( first_day ) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), LEVEL - 1 )
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
)
```

But, leaving that aside, your `add_days` case statement checks whether the date is the first of the month and then applies two different sets of logic to days that are or aren't the first of the month:

That section of your query can be written more simply as:

```sql
CASE
WHEN TO_CHAR (mydate, 'DD.MM')  = '01.01'
THEN CASE TO_CHAR( TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' ), 'fmD' )
     WHEN '7' THEN 2
     WHEN '6' THEN 3
              ELSE 1
     END
ELSE CASE TO_CHAR( TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' ), 'fmD' )
     WHEN '7' THEN 2
     WHEN '1' THEN 1       -- Different to the above
              ELSE 0       -- Again, different.
     END
END AS add_days
```

You will add a different number of days depending on whether the input date is the first day of the month or not and this is why you are getting duplicate rows for some months.

You query should (again, ignoring that you are generating too many rows) be something like:

```sql
WITH dateparam ( mydate ) AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') + LEVEL - 1
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' ), 12 ) - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'YYYY' )
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' ) bd_date,
       TO_CHAR( TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' ) , 'fmD') day_num,
       CASE TO_CHAR( TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' ), 'fmD')
       WHEN '7' THEN 2
       WHEN '1' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
       END add_days,
       TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' )
       + CASE TO_CHAR( TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' ), 'fmD')
         WHEN '7' THEN 2
         WHEN '1' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END date_calc
FROM dateparam
ORDER BY 1;
```

Which will work in any territory where the first day of the week is a Sunday ... which is not large swathes of the world. In those other places, your query will give an incorrect answer and, instead, if Monday is the first day of the week would shift Sunday and Monday to Tuesday.

For example:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'America';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD "("DY")"';
```

and the above query outputs:

> ```
> BD_DATE          | DAY_NUM | ADD_DAYS | DATE_CALC       
> :--------------- | :------ | -------: | :---------------
> 2020-01-01 (WED) | 4       |        0 | 2020-01-01 (WED)
> 2020-02-01 (SAT) | 7       |        2 | 2020-02-03 (MON)
> 2020-03-01 (SUN) | 1       |        1 | 2020-03-02 (MON)
> 2020-04-01 (WED) | 4       |        0 | 2020-04-01 (WED)
> 2020-05-01 (FRI) | 6       |        0 | 2020-05-01 (FRI)
> 2020-06-01 (MON) | 2       |        0 | 2020-06-01 (MON)
> 2020-07-01 (WED) | 4       |        0 | 2020-07-01 (WED)
> 2020-08-01 (SAT) | 7       |        2 | 2020-08-03 (MON)
> 2020-09-01 (TUE) | 3       |        0 | 2020-09-01 (TUE)
> 2020-10-01 (THU) | 5       |        0 | 2020-10-01 (THU)
> 2020-11-01 (SUN) | 1       |        1 | 2020-11-02 (MON)
> 2020-12-01 (TUE) | 3       |        0 | 2020-12-01 (TUE)
> ```

but:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TERRITORY = 'France';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD "("DY")"';
```

and it outputs:

> ```
> BD_DATE          | DAY_NUM | ADD_DAYS | DATE_CALC       
> :--------------- | :------ | -------: | :---------------
> 2020-01-01 (WED) | 3       |        0 | 2020-01-01 (WED)
> 2020-02-01 (SAT) | 6       |        0 | 2020-02-01 (SAT)
> 2020-03-01 (SUN) | 7       |        2 | 2020-03-03 (TUE)
> 2020-04-01 (WED) | 3       |        0 | 2020-04-01 (WED)
> 2020-05-01 (FRI) | 5       |        0 | 2020-05-01 (FRI)
> 2020-06-01 (MON) | 1       |        1 | 2020-06-02 (TUE)
> 2020-07-01 (WED) | 3       |        0 | 2020-07-01 (WED)
> 2020-08-01 (SAT) | 6       |        0 | 2020-08-01 (SAT)
> 2020-09-01 (TUE) | 2       |        0 | 2020-09-01 (TUE)
> 2020-10-01 (THU) | 4       |        0 | 2020-10-01 (THU)
> 2020-11-01 (SUN) | 7       |        2 | 2020-11-03 (TUE)
> 2020-12-01 (TUE) | 2       |        0 | 2020-12-01 (TUE)
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d34ec7c4c114e8e6332a739ba8063e1b)*

You either need to ensure that the `NLS_TERRITORY` setting never changes (however, **ANY** user can set it to whatever value they want in their session at any time) or use something that is agnostic to the NLS settings (like my example at the top). You cannot fix the query with the `D` format model by using the third argument of `TO_CHAR` as it only lets you set the `NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE` (which has no effect on the first day of the week) and does not accept an `NLS_TERRITORY` (which does control the first day of the week) but you could use the `DY` format model if you were really fixated on using `TO_CHAR`. I.e.:

```sql
CASE TO_CHAR( TRUNC( mydate, 'MM' ), 'DY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American' )
WHEN 'SAT' THEN 2
WHEN 'SUN' THEN 1
           ELSE 0
END add_days
```

Comment: No this isn't the issue. I've altered the NLS settings to use America. As you can see my problem is why I'm getting two rows when using a comparison to a date string. I'm not facing the wrong calculation of when the days are weekends as you can see from my results.

Comment: I'm not saying it is the issue; I'm saying that relying on NLS settings is a recipe for things to go wrong as not all countries start the week on the same day. I'm trying to debug your code a the moment.... but its just too complicated for what its trying to do and its taking a while to work out what it should do vs. what it is doing.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I am setting the NLS before each session so let's assume Sunday is the first day of the week. However having read through your explanation, I can understand the too many set of rows but its not clear how it's getting the value 0 for 01.01.2020. It can only get 0 if it fails in the first case block where I'm comparing it to '01.01' and then enter the else block where it can get 0 for a normal weekday. However I don't see why it should fail in the first comparison and even enter the else part of the case statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use following query:

```
with dates (dt) as
(select
add_months(trunc(sysdate,'year'),level-1)
from dual
connect by level <=12)
select dt, dt-dto as daysdiff from
(select case to_char(dt,'dy')
          when 'sat' 
          then dt+2 
          when 'sun'
          then dt+1
          else dt
          end as dt,
          dto
     from
(select case when extract(month from dt) = 1
       then dt + 1
       else dt 
       end as dt,
       dt as dto
  from dates))
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=97908e8ba3e27f597ac230fb5e758eb0) demo.

Comment: I can accept this works, but Id still like to try and understand what was wrong with my original query and why it doesn't work. Please also try and keep the format of my original table so the calculations are demonstrated.